# How to make a image clickable using document.getElementById in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, onclick

I am currently using the Twitch API, where I have created a file that renders the game cover image by searching. I want the user to be able to click the game image, which will redirect them to their proper Twitch Links

**Search Response**

[image: Search Response]

My code for the game image rendering looks like this:

```
render() {
const { game } = this.props

return (
  <div className="GameDetails">
      <img src={this.formatImageUrl(game.box_art_url)} alt="" />
      <p>{game.name} </p>
      <p>ID: {game.id}</p>
  </div>
   )
  }
 }

export default GameImage
```

I tried out:

```
render() {
  const { game } = this.props

return (
  <div className="GameDetails">
      <img src={this.formatImageUrl(game.box_art_url)} alt="" onClick${"https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/${document.getElementById("SearchName").value}"}/>
      <p>{game.name} </p>
      <p>ID: {game.id}</p>
 </div>
   )
  }
 }

 export default GameImage
```

Which gives me an error.
The "SearchName" value is what the user types in the search bar for the game, therefore I want to send them to the respectable twitch pages when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will receive an error, because firstly you've misspelled `$` with `=` and secondly, `onClick` prop expects a function which will handle the action after clicking the image.

Suggested approach:

```
handleClick = () => {
   // logic when user clicks on image
   // https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/${document.getElementById("SearchName").value}
}

render() {
  const { game } = this.props

  return (
    <div className="GameDetails">
      <img src={this.formatImageUrl(game.box_art_url)} alt="" onClick={this.handleClick} />
      <p>{game.name} </p>
      <p>ID: {game.id}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GameImage
```

**Edit**: It's kinda difficult to understand what you really want to achieve, however if you want that `img` to work as a link, you should consider using `a` element instead. Just wrap your `img` tag as well as `p` into `a`.

```
render() {
  const { game} = this.props
  const link = `https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/${document.getElementById("SearchName").value}`;

  return (
    <div className="GameDetails">
      <a href={link}>
        <img src={this.formatImageUrl(game.box_art_url)} alt="" onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <p>{game.name} </p>
        <p>ID: {game.id}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is go to another site by clicking on the image simply wrap it in an HTML anchor with the url as the `href` attribute. Hover over the images (don't click on them) to see the URL in the browser status bar.

```js
function App({ data }) {
  return data.map(game => <Details game={game} />);
}

function Details({ game }) {
  return (
    <div className="gameDetails">
      <a href={game.twitch_url}>
        <img src={game.box_art_url} />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

const data = [
  { id: 1, twitch_url: 'http://game1.com', box_art_url: 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff' },
  { id: 2, twitch_url: 'http://game2.com', box_art_url: 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/555/fff' },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.gameDetails {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```